# Will placing constraints on arbitrary method return types violate Bean Validation 1.0?

Tags: bean-validation

I'm aware that [Bean Validation 1.1 introduces support for validating arbitrary methods](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/1.1.0.cr3/#d0e331).

But will the adding of, say, a `@NotNull` constraint on an arbitrary method (such as, say, `@NotNull public Frobnicator frobnicate()`) cause problems in Bean Validation *1.0*?  Or should such metadata—I hope!—simply be ignored by a Bean Validation 1.0 validator?

(I can test this of course using Hibernate Validator, but that only tells me that this particular implementation either honors this state of affairs or does not; it does not tell me if it was the specification authors' intent to allow the placing of validation constraints on arbitrary methods in Bean Validation 1.0.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Validator 4.x (the reference implementation of BV 1.0) offers its [own API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-specifics.html#validator-customoptions-methodvalidation) for method validation, so method constraints could potentially be validated there.

But solely adding a constraint to a method doesn't cause its validation, instead you need some sort of method interceptor, AOP advice etc. to invoke the validation engine upon method validation. So I don't think you would see any unexpected side effects in BV 1.0.

I'd assume its the same for Apache BVAL which also has a feature for method validation.

Comment: Thank you; I should have mentioned that I'm chiefly concerned about validation in a JPA environment.  We got burned by simply placing `@NotNull` on the return type of an overloaded get-type method (one getter took no parameters; the other identically named one took one parameter; you can't put `@NotNull` on both of them).  I know of that case, but was looking for others.  Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my honest opinion, since the behavior isn't specified in the Validations 1.0 there is no way to tell that all implementations will do it the same.